# Aceptar letras y numeros en un input tipo texto

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buen día, tengo este código que solo permite el uso de números.

```
$('input[name="39"]').bind('keypress', function(e){
        var keyCode = (e.which)?e.which:event.keyCode
        return !(keyCode>31 && (keyCode<48 || keyCode>57)); 
});
```

pero ahora necesito que acepte números y letras, es decir después de que pase cierto evento que el `input` regrese a la normalidad.

```js
$('select#_38').on('change', function () {
        var varToTest = $(this).val();
        alert(varToTest)
        if (varToTest == 'nit'){
          $('input[name="39"]').bind('keypress', function(e) {
  var keyCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode
  return !(keyCode > 31 && (keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 90) && (keyCode < 97 || keyCode > 122));
});
        }else{
          $('input[name="39"]').bind('keypress', function(e){
        var keyCode = (e.which)?e.which:event.keyCode
        return !(keyCode>31 && (keyCode<48 || keyCode>57)); 
});
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="38[]" id="_38" data-placeholder="Seleccionar" class="form-control">
                        <option value="ced" selected="selected">Cédula de Ciudadanía</option>
                    <option value="nit">NIT</option>
                    <option value="pasa">Pasaporte</option>
                    <option value="identi">Tarjeta de Identidad</option>
                    <option value="extra">Cédula Extranjería</option>
                </select>


<input id="39" name="39" type="text">
```

No realiza correctamente el cambio, la idea es permitir letras y numeros cuando se selecciona NIT y cualquier otro solo numeros

Comment: Necesitas jquery? Porque podrías usar un pattern para el input text

Comment: Gracias @Carmen por responder, si es necesario jquery ya que no tengo acceso directo al input, en realidad necesito que el imput acepte numeros y el signo -

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solo debes agregar los códigos de los caracteres que deseas a la condición:

```js
$('input[name="39"]').bind('keypress', function(e) {
  var keyCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode
  return !(keyCode > 31 && (keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 90) && (keyCode < 97 || keyCode > 122));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="39" name="39" type="text">
```

Aplicado a tu código, lo que haria es declarar una variable global llamada `nitSeleccionado` y cuando cambie el valor del select utilizar esa variable como bandera que indique el cambio. Por el otro lado, en el `input text` solo verifico si el valor de la variable ya cambió.

```js
var nitSeleccionado = false;

$('select#_38').on('change', function() {
  var varToTest = $(this).val();
  alert(varToTest)
  if (varToTest == 'nit') {
    nitSeleccionado = true;
  } else {
    nitSeleccionado = false;
  }
});

$('input[name="39"]').bind('keypress', function(e) {
  var keyCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode
  if (nitSeleccionado) {
   return !(keyCode > 31 && (keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 90) && (keyCode < 97 || keyCode > 122));
  } else {
    return !(keyCode > 31 && (keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="38[]" id="_38" data-placeholder="Seleccionar" class="form-control">
  <option value="ced" selected="selected">Cédula de Ciudadanía</option>
  <option value="nit">NIT</option>
  <option value="pasa">Pasaporte</option>
  <option value="identi">Tarjeta de Identidad</option>
  <option value="extra">Cédula Extranjería</option>
</select>

<input id="39" name="39" type="text">
```

---

Nota: Como ultimo dato, yo preferiria cambiar la validación del teclado para permitir el uso de la tecla delete, las flechas de dirección y y la tecla ctrl/cmd para mayor libertad en el uso del input. Tambien vaciar el input cada vez que el select cambia. Para compatibilidad con el telefono es necesario utilizar `keydown` en lugar de `keypress`:

```js
var nitSeleccionado = false;

$('select#_38').on('change', function() {
  var varToTest = $(this).val();
  alert(varToTest);
  $('input[name="39"]').val("");
  if (varToTest == 'nit') {
    nitSeleccionado = true;
  } else {
    nitSeleccionado = false;
  }
});

$('input[name="39"]').bind('keydown', function(e) {
  var keyCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode
  if (nitSeleccionado) {
   return e.metaKey || // cmd/ctrl
    e.which <= 0 || // arrow keys
    e.which == 8 || // delete key
    /[a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which)); // numbers
  } else {
    return e.metaKey || // cmd/ctrl
    e.which <= 0 || // arrow keys
    e.which == 8 || // delete key
    /[0-9]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which)); // numbers
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="38[]" id="_38" data-placeholder="Seleccionar" class="form-control">
  <option value="ced" selected="selected">Cédula de Ciudadanía</option>
  <option value="nit">NIT</option>
  <option value="pasa">Pasaporte</option>
  <option value="identi">Tarjeta de Identidad</option>
  <option value="extra">Cédula Extranjería</option>
</select>

<input id="39" name="39" type="text">
```

Comment: Hola Gracias por Responder, te comento lo que estoy tratando de realizar es esto [https://jsbin.com/yuzogocicu/2/edit?html,js,output] sin embargo no funciona

Comment: ¿la respuesta resolvió tu duda?

Comment: aqui en Stack overflow tambien hay fiddles para hacer códigos ejecutables, por favor edita la pregunta y añade ese código explicando más a detalle el problema para que lo podamos resolver.

Comment: Gracias amigo, tu respuesta ha sido clara y me ha funcionado, Un saludo

Comment: Hola, te comento el código no me funciona desde mi teléfono, que habría que realizar en ese caso

Comment: intenta usar **keyup** en lugar de **keypress** y dime si funciona

Comment: sustituí **keypress** por **keydown**  y parece funcionar

Comment: No funciona en mi telefono, en el ordenador lo hace exelente (https://softest.corpochivor.gov.co/open.php)

Comment: Ya estuve revisando y parece que el teclado del telefono siempre marca el código **229**. Es un tema complicado que incluso deberia ser una pregunta nueva, aún no encuentro la solución pero esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42552368/4987172) te puede ayudar